# Block until file in directory changes

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I want to use watchdog to block until a file changes in a directory.  What I'm doing is sleeping while a variable is `False`.  The problem with this, though, is that I can't interrupt the sleep; there's still up to 1s delay to break when the file changes.  How can I break out of the sleep and continue to the point after the sleep?  Or more generically, block until a file changes?  Here's my code:

```
import sys
import time
import os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
  observer = Observer()

  def nothing():
    pass

  class FileChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    done = False

    def on_any_event(self, event):
      print 'Got event'
      FileChangeHandler.done = True

  path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
  event_handler = FileChangeHandler()
  observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
  observer.start()

  while not event_handler.done:
    time.sleep(1)

  print 'Done'

  observer.stop()
  observer.join()
```

Comment: You could sleep for a shorter amount of time, like a millisecond. You wouldn't have a noticeable delay.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that you can specify the seconds as a floating point number.  The response time is good.  I was looking for a signaling/event approach, which I couldn't get working, but would sleeping be just as good?